# Apache Rewrite Rule that Only redirects traffic on even timestamps

Tags: apache, redirect, apache2, httpd.conf, regex

I am trying to create an apache redirect rule that will redirect half of my traffic to one location.

The way I want to do this is by only redirecting traffic that arrives with an even timestamp. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: can you please provide more details, like URLs, destination. this will make our answers as accurate as possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if it's a smart ting to do, but you could do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{TIME_SEC} \d[0,2,4,6,8]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://other.server.net/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Edit: Changed from DATE_LOCAL to TIME_SEC. Which made the regular expression better

Comment: @Peter , hope my latest update works for you. Works fine on my server.